# Find free port in Java

Tags: java, port, ip-address, javadoc, inet-socket

I need to find a free port in a Java Application. Why doesn't the below code work? It always returns 0.

```
public int findFreePort() {
    int portNumber = new InetSocketAddress(0).getPort();
    return portNumber;
}
```

Java doc of `new InetSocketAddress()` says:

Creates a socket address where the IP address is the wildcard address and the port number a specified value.

A valid port value is between 0 and 65535. A port number of zero will let the system pick up an ephemeral port in a bind operation.

Comment: "In a bind operation". You haven't bound it.

Comment: To get a free port you have to attempt to bind to port 0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually you output the port member that you specified in the constructor. So `0` is expected.
The javadoc states that the port will let the system pick up an ephemeral port for a binding operation. 
It doesn't tell that the port number will be valued with the ephemeral port directly in the `InetSocketAddress` instance.
Actually you don't execute a binding operation with this `InetSocketAddress` instance.
In clear you didn't open/create a socket channel to communicate with this instance.
So you cannot notice the result of the port.

For example this binds the a `ServerSocket` to a `InetSocketAddress`   :

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(..);
ss.bind(new InetSocketAddress(0));
```

Here is a more complete example illustrating how things work :

```
public class InetSockerAddressWithEphemeralPortMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        InetSocketAddress randomSocketAddressFirst = new InetSocketAddress(0);

        try (ServerSocket ssOne = new ServerSocket()) {
            System.out.println("randomSocketAddress port before any binding : " + randomSocketAddressFirst.getPort());
            ssOne.bind(randomSocketAddressFirst);
            System.out.println("local port after first binding :" + ssOne.getLocalPort());
        }

        try (ServerSocket ssTwo = new ServerSocket()) {
            ssTwo.bind(randomSocketAddressFirst);
            System.out.println("local port after second binding :" + ssTwo.getLocalPort());
            System.out.println("randomSocketAddress port after all bindings : " + randomSocketAddressFirst.getPort());
        }

    }
}
```

Output :

> randomSocketAddress port before any binding : 0
>
> local port after first binding : 65110
>
> local port after second binding : 65111
>
> randomSocketAddress port after all bindings : 0

You can see that the `InetSocketAddress` object keeps always `0` as port value while the  `ServerSocket` objects benefit from a picked up ephemeral port.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find a free port to use in your code, do:

```java
private static int findFreePort() {
    int port = 0;
    // For ServerSocket port number 0 means that the port number is automatically allocated.
    try (ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(0)) {
        // Disable timeout and reuse address after closing the socket.
        socket.setReuseAddress(true);
        port = socket.getLocalPort();
    } catch (IOException ignored) {}
    if (port > 0) {
        return port;
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Could not find a free port");
}
```

Comment: No need for `setReuseAddress` I believe